# Firebase user is logged out on page reload | FirebaseAuthError: Decoding Firebase ID token failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am currently using `firebase` for auth in my web application and one particular issue that I have been facing is that even though the user did not sign out from the application if I reload the page and try to access the current user's `accessToken` using the following snippet of [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  const userAccessToken = user?.accesstoken;
   
  doStuff(userAccessToken); // some placeholder function which takes the `userAccessToken` as one of the parameters
});
```

The `user` object is `null` thus indicating the user is signed out. How do I prevent this from happening? Is there a way to ensure that the user stays signed in unless he explicitly signs out from the application?

The `onAuthStateChanged` must always return the `user` as `not null` unless he signs out. The page reloads or any other kind of navigation or operations must not affect this state.

This has particularly been a problem since I require the `jwt` token of the currently signed-in user to carry out authorization tasks in the backend. The `firebase-admin` function

```js
const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(authJwtToken);
```

upon receiving `null` errors out

> FirebaseAuthError: Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token.

Comment: You need to assign a cookie header as a response for the user to remember and request each time they access so they can get that "ID" and use it as their own. Each HTTP request will be unique but given the cookie ID will be the same that can be used to identify a session or in your case a firebase user. The values however should have a time-to-live (TTL).

Comment: "Is there a way to ensure that the user stays signed in unless he explicitly signs out from the application?" That is actually the default behavior for Firebase Authentication on most environments, it persists the auth state to local storage and restores it when the page or app reloads. Where are you running this code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ubuntu 20.04 on my local machine as well the project is hosted on firebase. It does not work in either dev or prod emvironments.

Comment: I was more curious in what browser you test this, or whether it runs as a React Native app. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am running it on Chrome Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (64-bit). It is a React app not React native app.

Comment: Hmmm... as said, the Firebase SDK should be persisting user credentials automatically there. I'm not sure why that wouldn't work, so it might be worth checking the JavaScript console for any relevant messages, and possibly seeing it there's a way to get debug output from the SDK.